# Why System.Text.Json Fails to Deserialize Json to Generic Class

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have two classes and enum:

```
public abstract class Changed
{
    public abstract object OldValue { get; set; }
    public abstract object NewValue { get; set; }
    public TrackedPropertyType Type { get; set; }
}
    
public class Changed<T> : Changed
{
    public override object OldValue { get; set; }
    public override object NewValue { get; set; }
    
    public Changed(T oldValue, T newValue, TrackedPropertyType type)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
        Type = type;
    }
}

public enum TrackedPropertyType
{
    PhoneNumber,
    Name,
    Email,
    BirthDate,
    WorkedInDodo,
    SocialNetworkMessagingEnable,
    IsKeyWord,
    IsBanned,
    IsFraud,
    IsRemove,
}
```

I can serialize instance of this class to json without any problem. For example:

```
{"type": 6, "newValue": 1, "oldValue": 2}
```

or

```
{"type": 5, "newValue": true, "oldValue": true}
```

but when I try deserialize it like this:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Changed<string>>(json, options);
```

I'm getting:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Each parameter in the
> deserialization constructor on type
> 'Dodo.Control.Ratings.Model.MysteryShoppers.Events.Changed`1[System.Boolean]'
> must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each
> parameter name must match with a property or field on the object.
> Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields'
> is enabled. The match can be case-insensitive.

Options contain:

- PropertyNameCaseInsensitive: true
- JsonCamelCaseNamingPolicy: JsonCamelCaseNamingPolicy

Comment: It's because the **types** of constructor arguments do not match the types of the properties.  The properties have type `object` but the arguments have type `T`.  See e.g. [Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type must bind to an object property or field on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72510474/3744182).  Does that answer your question, or do you need additional help?

Comment: And how to fix it? I want to have collection of different changed instances. With different T types. That's why I'm using base class

Comment: Will the *collection of different changed instances* contain **polymorphic** entries?  I.e. it will be declared as `List<Changed>` but contain e.g. `Changed<string>`, `Changed<bool>` and `Changed<int>` entries?  And will you need to serialize and deserialize the collection retaining the concrete types of each item?

Comment: Yes it will be declared as List<Changed> and will contain entries of different types string, int etc

Comment: I think I can handle types after diserialization based on enum property

Comment: Then you may need to look into [polymorphic serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352597/3744182).

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Have you tried making 'type' the first parameter in the Deserialization constructor. If that doesn't help, try explicitly annotating the constrcutor to be used as the deserialization constructor, by using the "JsonConstructor" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.
Edit, I upgraded the example to serialize and deserialize a complex object.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Changed<TestClass> changedTestClass = new Changed<TestClass>();

        changedTestClass.NewValue = new TestClass() { 
            Name = "Test class 2",
            Id = 2,
            PropertyType = TrackedPropertyType.Email
        };

        changedTestClass.OldValue = new TestClass() { 
            Name = "Test class 1",
            Id = 1,
            PropertyType = TrackedPropertyType.PhoneNumber
        };

        var stringResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(changedTestClass);
        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Changed<TestClass>>(stringResult);
       
    }
}

public class Changed<T> : IValues<T>
{
    public T OldValue { get; set; }
    public T NewValue { get; set; }
    public TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
}

public interface IValues<T> { 
    T OldValue { get; set; }

    T NewValue { get; set; }

    TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

}



public enum TrackedPropertyType
{
    PhoneNumber,
    Name,
    Email,
    BirthDate,
    WorkedInDodo,
    SocialNetworkMessagingEnable,
    IsKeyWord,
    IsBanned,
    IsFraud,
    IsRemove,
}
```

The problem is specifically that "object" is a type, and `<T>` can be a different type than object declaration wise.

The deserializer does not know what to expect.

If you force the values to be the declaring type `<T>`, you will not confuse the serializer. I am trying to convey this is simply as possible, and realize this might not be 100% accurate. But should suffice for now.

Edit 2:
If you, for some odd reason insist that the abstract keyword is used: (Also I am sorry, I am not really thinking it through anymore, just copy pasting, but seriously, it shouldn't be a problem to modify this example into whatever extended features you want.)

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            ChangedTestClass<TestClass> changedTestClass = new ChangedTestClass<TestClass>();

            changedTestClass.NewValue = new TestClass() { 
                Name = "Test class 2",
                Id = 2,
                PropertyType = TrackedPropertyType.Email
            };

            changedTestClass.OldValue = new TestClass() { 
                Name = "Test class 1",
                Id = 1,
                PropertyType = TrackedPropertyType.PhoneNumber
            };

            var stringResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(changedTestClass);
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ChangedTestClass<TestClass>>(stringResult);
           
        }
    }

    public abstract class Changed<T> : IValues<T>
    {
        public T OldValue { get; set; }
        public T NewValue { get; set; }
        public TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChangedTestClass<TestClass> {
        public TestClass OldValue { get; set; }
        public TestClass NewValue { get; set; }
        public TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    }


    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    }
    
    public interface IValues<T> { 
        T OldValue { get; set; }

        T NewValue { get; set; }

        TrackedPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

    }

    

    public enum TrackedPropertyType
    {
        PhoneNumber,
        Name,
        Email,
        BirthDate,
        WorkedInDodo,
        SocialNetworkMessagingEnable,
        IsKeyWord,
        IsBanned,
        IsFraud,
        IsRemove,
    }
```

Comment: The main idea of using abstract class is to have opportunity to create collection of Changed class with different underlying types:
List<Changed> data = new List<Changed>();
data.Add(new Changed<int>());
data.Add(new Changed<bool>());
and so on.
It seems that approach that your provided is lacking in this department.

Comment: @Fallingsappy, could you be a bit more specific? 
I don't see that it is lacking? But perhaps, since your question doesn't actually have this information in the question, that would have been relevant to provide?

Comment: Sorry. I think your answer indeed solves the original questions, so I would mark it as answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Fallingsappy If you are still seeing an issue, after this resolution, please post another question, and link it in the comment here, I will gladly take a look at issues that arise further down the line ;)