# C# Json Deserialize not working with parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

How does JsonSerializer.Deserialize work with a parameterized constructor?

In the below example, Foo1 works as expected, but when Foo2 uses a constructor instead of properties, it errors:

```
        public class Foo1
        {
            public string propA { get; set; } = "";
            public string propB { get; set; } = "";
            public void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propA);
                Console.WriteLine(propB);
            }
        }
        public class Foo2
        {
            [JsonConstructor]
            public Foo2(string propA, string propB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propA);
                Console.WriteLine(propB);
            }
        }
        static void TestDeserialize()
        {
            string json = """{"propA":"aaa","propB":"bbb"}""";

            Foo1? foo1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo1>(json);
            foo1.Print();

            // error is on the below line:
            Foo2? foo2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo2>(json);
        }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll`
> Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Foo2' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive.

It certainly looks like each parameter binds to a property.

**Edit**: it certainly looks like each *constructor parameter* binds to a *JSON property*, which seems like a necessary and reasonable requirement. If each constructor parameter needs to bind to a *C# property*, that would be a strange requirement since Deserialize is just calling the constructor, and shouldn't interact with properties. Not to mention that if this is the error (as it seems it might be), it could be a compile-time error, diagnosed on seeing Foo2, rather than waiting to see the JSON.

Comment: Foo2 has no properties or fields so the parameters in the constructor can’t bind to any property. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Did you intend for `Foo2` to derive from `Foo1`, so it inherits the properties?

Comment: I thought the error is that each *constructor parameter* must bind to a *JSON property*. I want to make a class that doesn't have string properties, e.g. on the final Foo2 class, I will process the strings in the constructor, rather than just setting them to properties. Can JsonSerializer.Deserialize call the constructor without worrying about what my class does with the constructor parameters?

Comment: If JsonSerializer.Deserialize needs *Foo2 C# properties* to exist, even though it shouldn't be interacting with them in any way, that would be disappointing.

Comment: @imMAW - the requirement is [documented precisely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability): *The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the **property names and types**. Matching is case-insensitive, and the constructor parameter must match the actual property name even if you use `[JsonPropertyName]` to rename a property.*  The fact that MSFT means "C# property" not "JSON property" can be seen from example code.

Comment: See also [Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type must bind to an object property or field on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72510474/3744182), which looks to be similar or a duplicate.

Comment: @dbc Ok, this answers my question (even if not the answer I was hoping for).

Comment: @imMAW - you could always write a `JsonConverter` with the necessary logic.

Answer (score 0):

you have some quite bad bugs in your code, class Foo2 doesn't make any sense. I guess it should be

```
public class Foo2:Foo1
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Foo2(string propA, string propB)
    {
        this.propA=propA;
        this.propB=propB;
        Console.WriteLine(propA);
        Console.WriteLine(propB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Foo2 should not have those properties. I want Deserialize to pass the strings to the constructor *instead* of directly setting properties. In the real code I want to write, the constructor will process the strings and end up storing more advanced information on Foo2.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json in this case