# .Net 7,8 System.Text.Json Deserialize Polymorphic Parameter

Tags: .net, deserialization, system.text.json, .net-8.0

I have a class structure I can Serialize and Deserialize no problem. I have demonstrated it below in a contrived example

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Apple),typeDiscriminator: "apple")]
public abstract class Fruit
{
    public Seed seed { get; }

    protected Fruit(Seed seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }
}

public sealed class Apple : Fruit
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Apple(Seed seed) : base(seed) { }
}

public sealed class AppleSeed : Seed
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public AppleSeed() {}
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(AppleSeed),typeDiscriminator: "apple")]
public abstract class Seed { }
```

But I want the Apple constructor to require the type AppleSeed:

```
[JsonConstructor]
    public Apple(AppleSeed seed) : base(seed) { }
```

This serializes fine but fails to deserialize since the deserializer needs the base class info. I attempted to use generics to fix this but couldn't work it out. Is there a reliable way to deserialize polymorphic parameters using System.Text.Json without implementing a custom deserializer? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  I can round-trip `Fruit fruit = new Apple(new AppleSeed());` successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/kiptzX.  Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: Sry. I should have started with the failing code. your dotfiddle does not have `public Apple(AppleSeed seed) : base(seed) { }`. I think the Deserializer needs the reference to the base Seed class when deserializing Apple.

Comment: OK I see.  You need to add `public new AppleSeed seed { get => (AppleSeed)base.seed; }` to `Apple`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kfa65D.  Is that an acceptable answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `public Apple(AppleSeed seed) : base(seed) { }` constructor is explained in the documentation page [Use immutable types and properties: Parameterized constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability#parameterized-constructors):

> The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the property names **and types**.

Since the constructor parameter type `AppleSeed seed` does not match the property type `Seed seed`, the constructor parameter cannot be used.  Failing demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kiptzX).

The easiest workaround is to hide the base type property with a [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) property of the same name and the required type:

```
public sealed class Apple : Fruit
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Apple(AppleSeed seed) : base(seed) { }
    
    public new AppleSeed seed => (AppleSeed)base.seed;
}
```

See also:

- [Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type must bind to an object property or field on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72000907/3744182).
- [[JsonSerializer] Relax restrictions on ctor param type to immutable property type matching where reasonable #44428](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44428).

Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kfa65D).

Comment: Great solution. Thanks @dbc. A word of caution for anyone using this. The polymorphic parameter won't serialize with $type info. In this case you get `{"$type":"apple","seed":{}}` instead of `{"$type":"apple","seed":{$type:"apple"}}`. This is preferrable for me but you'll notice serializing just `seed` will give you {"$type":"apple"}. In case that is confusing. Thanks again!

Comment: @BradleyImpl - right, the `"$type":"apple"` type discriminator is omitted for `seed` because the parent type was specified to be `Apple` so the property type for `seed` is unambiguous and so not polymorphic.