Problem when deserializing a nested object JSON
I have an application on WinForms for one user that stores a list of categories of expenses and income, as well as expenses and income themselves.
public class User
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return AmountOfExpensesAndIncomes + UserAllowance;
        }
        set { }
    }
    public List<Expenditure> Expenses { get; set; }
    public List<Income> Incomes { get; set; }
    public List<ExpenseCategory> ExpenseCategories { get; set; }
    public List<IncomeCategory> IncomesCategories { get; set; }
    public decimal UserAllowance { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public decimal AmountOfExpensesAndIncomes
    {
        get
        {
            decimal sum = 0;
            foreach (var expenditure in Expenses)
                sum -= expenditure.Amount;

            foreach (var income in Incomes)
                sum += income.Amount;

            return sum;
        }
    }

    public User()
    {
        Balance = 0;
        Expenses = new();
        Incomes = new();    
        ExpenseCategories = [new("Другое")];
        IncomesCategories = [new("Другое")];

    }
}
public abstract class Category
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected Category(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
public class ExpenseCategory : Category
{
    public ExpenseCategory(string title) : base(title) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
public class IncomeCategory : Category
{
    public IncomeCategory(string title) : base(title) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
public abstract class Operation
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Operation(DateTime date, decimal amount, Category category, string description)
    {
        Date = date;
        Amount = amount;
        Category = category;
        Description = description;
    }
}
public class Expenditure : Operation
{
    public Expenditure(DateTime date, decimal amount, ExpenseCategory category,string description) 
        : base(date, amount, category, description) { }
}
    public class Income : Operation
    {
        public Income(DateTime date, decimal amount, IncomeCategory category, string description) 
            : base(date, amount, category, description) { }      
    }

There are no problems with sterilization itself. But with deserialization (if there is already some expense and income (if not, then everything is fine)) an error occurs.
internal class SerializableSaver
{
    public static T Load<T>() where T : class
    {
        var fileName = $"{typeof(T).Name}.json";

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void Save<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        var fileName = $"{typeof(T).Name}.json";
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, json);
    }
}


Serialization occurs when the form is closed, and deserialization occurs in the form field
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    SerializableSaver.Save(user);
}
User user = SerializableSaver.Load<User>() ?? new User();

{
  "Expenses": [
    {
      "Date": "2024-04-07T17:09:28.8432006+03:00",
      "Amount": 50,
      "Category": {
        "Title": "Food"
      },
      "Description": ""
    }
  ],
  "Incomes": [],
  "ExpenseCategories": [
    {
      "Title": "\u0414\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043E\u0435"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Food"
    }
  ],
  "IncomesCategories": [
    {
      "Title": "\u0414\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043E\u0435"
    }
  ],
  "UserAllowance": 100
}

Exception when trying to deserialize when the user has added at least 1 expense:


InvalidOperationException: Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Expenditure' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled. The match can be case-insensitive.

If you delete a user's expense, the balance and its categories are saved and displayed correctly

Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your stack trace as text rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? for why.

check this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72000907/each-parameter-in-the-deserialization-constructor-on-type-must-bind-to-an-object

So If we initialize parameterless constructors for the classes, we make progress. Basically JsonDeserialization needs a parameterless constructor if you dont tell it how to handle the normal constructors. But then we run into a different problem: Category. Category is a abstract class, which on its own isnt a bad thing BUT you cant initialize a abstract class. Category cat = new Category("Title"); will throw you an error whilst Category cat = new IncomeCategory("Title"); will not. Expenditure and Income need to have their OWN Category attributes that arent inherited from Operation

Or we make Category NOT abstract

Might I ask why Expense and Income Category are different classes?
